# ImageMagick: split multipage 32 float TIFF image

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, tiff, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to convert 32-bit multipage TIFF image to several single TIFF images.

Command from [here](https://superuser.com/a/44602/213959)

`convert -depth 32 temp.tif single%d.tif`

```
convert: Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 33922 (0x8482) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 34735 (0x87af) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 34736 (0x87b0) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 34737 (0x87b1) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 42113 (0xa481) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Sorry, can not handle images with 32-bit samples. `temp.tif' @ error/ti
ff.c/TIFFErrors/565.
convert: Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 33922 (0x8482) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 34735 (0x87af) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 34736 (0x87b0) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 34737 (0x87b1) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 42113 (0xa481) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Sorry, can not handle images with 32-bit samples. `temp.tif' @ error/ti
ff.c/TIFFErrors/565.
convert: Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 33922 (0x8482) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 34735 (0x87af) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 34736 (0x87b0) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 34737 (0x87b1) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 42113 (0xa481) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Sorry, can not handle images with 32-bit samples. `temp.tif' @ error/ti
ff.c/TIFFErrors/565.
convert: Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 33922 (0x8482) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 34735 (0x87af) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 34736 (0x87b0) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 34737 (0x87b1) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 42113 (0xa481) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Sorry, can not handle images with 32-bit samples. `temp.tif' @ error/ti
ff.c/TIFFErrors/565.
convert: Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 33922 (0x8482) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 34735 (0x87af) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 34736 (0x87b0) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 34737 (0x87b1) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 42113 (0xa481) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Sorry, can not handle images with 32-bit samples. `temp.tif' @ error/ti
ff.c/TIFFErrors/565.
convert: Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 33922 (0x8482) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 34735 (0x87af) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 34736 (0x87b0) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 34737 (0x87b1) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Unknown field with tag 42113 (0xa481) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'
@ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/905.
convert: Sorry, can not handle images with 32-bit samples. `temp.tif' @ error/ti
ff.c/TIFFErrors/565.
```

Seems it can't work with 32-bit images by default `convert: Sorry, can not handle images with 32-bit samples`.

`convert -version`

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.2-6 Q16 x64 2016-07-30 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Visual C++: 180040629
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo flif freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr openexr pa
ngocairo png ps rsvg tiff webp xml zlib
```

Is there any way to do it with ImageMagick?

Comment: Do you have a sample image you can share please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, here is sample http://rgho.st/6j5HNLvXx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mmmm, I have tried Q16 and Q32, HDRI and Non-HDRI versions of ImageMagick with most combinations of most of these options:

- -define quantum:format=floating-point
- -depth 32
- -define tiff:ignore-tags=42113,34737,34736
- -define quantum:format=signed

and I can't get anywhere either!

I did have some success, I think with `vips` which is a fairly light-weight, easily installed package but it kind of depends what you want to do with the data afterwards:

Either you could convert each "page" straight from TIF to 32-bit PNG with this:

```
vips im_vips2png temp.tif:1 1.png
vips im_vips2png temp.tif:2 2.png
```

Or, you could go the long way round via `PPM` format:

```
# Convert first "page" in TIF to vips format
vips im_tiff2vips temp.tif:1 1.v

# Convert second "page" in TIF to vips format
vips im_tiff2vips temp.tif:2 2.v
```

... and so on for all 5 pages.

Then I can convert those to float PPMs with `vips`

```
vips ppmsave 1.v 1.ppm
vips ppmsave 2.v 2.ppm
```

And now ImageMagick can process the PPM files:

```
convert 1.ppm a.png
```

It kind of depends what you want to do next...

Comment: The problem is that I don't need `png` or `ppm` I need 32-bit tiff as result.

Comment: Seems it works: `"bin/vips.exe" im_tiff2vips temp.tif:1 1.v
"bin/vips.exe" tiffsave 1.v 1.tiff `

Comment: Also work on `Ubuntu 12.04 (sudo apt-get install libvips-tools)` like `vips im_vips2tiff dem_1.tif:1 1.tif`.

Comment: Also indeces start from `0`. so it would be `vips im_vips2tiff dem_1.tif:0 1.tif`

Comment: Also another problem is how to save metadata in resulting `1.tif` image? during convertion it prints lots of `vips warning: TIFFReadDirectory: Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered` , partially solved here : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283740/gdal-transfer-metainformation

Answer (score 1):

The [tiff](/questions/tagged/tiff) format is highly extendable, and I would suggest finding/researching the proprietary software used to generate the images.

Following [Mark's fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38785793/438117), I was able to research the following...

### Private Tiff Tags

- GeoTIFF

  - 0x830e - [ModelPixelScaleTag](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/modelpixelscaletag.html)
  - 0x8482 - [ModelTiepointTag](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/modeltiepointtag.html)
  - 0x87af - [GeoKeyDirectoryTag](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/geokeydirectorytag.html)
  - 0x87b0 - [GeoDoubleParamsTag](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/geodoubleparamstag.html)
  - 0x87b1 - [GeoAsciiParamsTag](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/geoasciiparamstag.html)
- GDAL library

  - 0xa481 - [GDAL_NODATA](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/gdal_nodata.html)

### TIFF Errors

> convert: Sorry, can not handle images with 32-bit samples. `temp.tif' @ error/tiff.c/TIFFErrors/564

This message comes from libtiff library that was linked to by ImageMagick. It simply doesn't support `TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE` of 32-bit per sample. Here's a code-snippet of `TIFFRGBAImageBegin` method used by the tiff library.

```c
TIFFGetFieldDefaulted(tif, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, &img->bitspersample);
switch (img->bitspersample) {
case 1: case 2: case 4:
case 8: case 16:
break;
default:
sprintf(emsg, "Sorry, can not handle images with %d-bit samples",
    img->bitspersample);
return (0);
}
```

### Alternative tiffsplit

If the task is just to spite the layers into isolated images, perhaps the `tiffsplit` will work...

```
tiffsplit temp.tif single_
```

... which will generate `single_aaa.tif`, `single_aab.tif`, & etc.

However the last layer of the image appears corrupt :(

[image: 6th layer]

Comment: At this point I don't need TIFF metadata, so it can be dropped. Seems that TIFF lib don't support 3 channel 32-bit images, but it should support 32-bit one channel images which is my case.